# How to fetch RealTime MS Outlook 365 inbox?

Tags: asp.net-core, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have integrated the On behalf User flow for my project requirement.

How do I access the multiple user's email account and fetch the Realtime Inbox and Save to DB on basis of Authorization token of every user which expires every hour in API based application?

Answer (score 1):

Did you read about Change notifications in Microsoft Graph?
There is a possibility to send webhook on specific change - for example, Outlook message: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#supported-resources

There is a whole tutorial for how to receive those notifications:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/change-notifications